# Array.length in Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to get length from array but it worked abnormally. Here is my object,

```
var user = {
  "username":"testuser update",
  "email":"user001@mail.co.th",
  "name":"user001",
  "ownAccount":"[
    {"id":2,"name":"Demo Account2"},
    {"id":1,"name":"Demo Account"}
  ]"
}
```

I want to get length of ownAccount, I tested by logging it,

```
console.log(user.ownAccount.length);
```

It showed **64** !!!, it didn't show **2**. 
I didn't understand what I did wrong.

Thanks for help.

Comment: try console.log(Object.keys(user).length);

Comment: The JSON you've posted is invalid - but on the face of it it looks like `ownAccount` might actually contain a string representation of an array, rather than the array directly?

Comment: You should get a [`SyntaxError` here](http://jsfiddle.net/u25u7yn9/), because you can't have a newline in a Javascript string like that

Comment: If you got this from a server, show how you get it. Because all this shows in declaring an object. I expect you have just copied and pasted some console output which is why it looks invalid

Comment: If you get 64 then that will be the length of the string, as expected. Which means you most probably do have a valid object to some degree, but the `ownAccount` property has also been stringified... I expect your JSON formatting is wrong server-side, but the work around is to directly parse the `ownAccount` property. As shown by @VickyGonsalves

Answer (score 2):

Its not an array you need to parse it first to get as an array :

```
var ownAc=JSON.parse(user.ownAccount)
console.log(ownAc.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the simple method `Object.keys(obj)` with the reference of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

In your case the answer is `Object.keys(user.ownAccount).length`

```js
var user = {
  "username": "testuser update",
  "email": "user001@mail.co.th",
  "name": "user001",
  "ownAccount": [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Demo Account2"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Demo Account"
    }
  ]
};

console.log(Object.keys(user.ownAccount).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `array` is defined as a `string`, you should remove the double quotes.
In other terms, replace `"[` with `[` and `]"` with `]`.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem for Double quotes

**"[**
    {"id":2,"name":"Demo Account2"},
    {"id":1,"name":"Demo Account"}
  **]"**

### Solution to remove the double quotes (if your array is your manual format)

try this code

```
  [
    {"id":2,"name":"Demo Account2"},
    {"id":1,"name":"Demo Account"}
  ]
```

### Solution (to if this array coming from any third parties)

try this code with your json data

```
var user = {
  "username":"testuser update",
  "email":"user001@mail.co.th",
  "name":"user001",
  "ownAccount":"[
    {"id":2,"name":"Demo Account2"},
    {"id":1,"name":"Demo Account"}
  ]"
}

user.ownAccount = JSON.parse(user.ownAccount)
console.log(user.ownAccount.length);
```

Comment: If the array came from any service, then he could not delete the double quotes. So i have overwriting the changed array with him array.

Comment: Don't downvote other peoples answers just because you want yours to be the top one

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var user = {
  username:"testuser update",
  email:"user001@mail.co.th",
  name:"user001",
  ownAccount:[
    {id:2,name:"Demo Account2"},
    {id:1,name:"Demo Account"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Deleting my duplicate answer in favor of this one

Comment: I received this obj from sever.I can't change it.

Comment: Then server side code is not formatting proper JSON.
use @Vicky Gonsalves answer